# Powershell send-mailmessage failing

Tags: powershell

I am running this PowerShell command from a cmd .bat script. It appears to be complaining about 'Request' as an argument. The only 'Request' in the command is inside quotes. What's going on?

```
M:>powershell send-mailmessage -to "pwatson@company.com" -from "pwatson@company.com" -subject "Standard Extract Request" -SmtpServer "mail.company.com" -attachment "file.txt"

Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Request'.
At line:1 char:1
+ send-mailmessage -to pwatson@company.com -from pwatson@company.com -subject Stan ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: are you running this from CMD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run PowerShell statements from CMD you must enclose the entire statement in double quotes. Use single quotes inside that string wherever possible.

```
powershell.exe -Command "Send-MailMessage -To 'pwatson@company.com' -From 'pwatson@company.com' -Subject 'Standard Extract Request' -SmtpServer 'mail.company.com' -Attachment 'file.txt'"
```